# What replaces binder2nd in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, std

I'm converting some code from C++03 to C++11, and I get a warning that `std::binder2nd<std::modulus<int> >` is deprecated. I've seen examples for replacing `bind2nd` calls with `bind`, but what replaces the `binder2nd` class?

Comment: `decltype(std::bind(...))` - not kidding, the return type of `std::bind` is unspecified. In any case, you shouldn't need to store such a value, and as such shouldn't need its type. If you actually do, it might be better to create your own function object for it.

Comment: `auto` or template arguments. And if you really really can't use those, `std::function<int(int)>`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour In which way would this change anything for him? What is the type of a lambda?

Comment: @ChristianRau I see what you mean, the standard actually says that `bind` provides a better solution, is there a reason you don't recommend something like `auto f1 = std::bind( std::modulus<int>(), _1, 10 )`?

Comment: It seems Xeo answer is correct. In this case, I needed the type of the object returned from the `bind` statement, as it was used a template argument in multiple places. It seems that if I want to literally replace the `bind1st` and `bind2nd` calls with `bind`, I have to use `decltype` where `binder1st` and `binder2nd` appear.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor: I don't quite see why you would explicitly pass them as template arguments. Got any sample code? It can highly likely be improved.

Comment: @Xeo it's not my code, but part of a project I was trying to get compiled with C++11. I don't really intend to do any maintenance on it beyond compilability.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour *"is there a reason you don't recommend something like..."* - That's exactly what I recommended in my comment.